# How to declare a multiple arraylist in java

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have a problem to declare a mulitple arraylist.
... missing the correct syntax or mixed up my mind ...

This works fine till here, to declare an arraylist with an array:

```
Integer[] arrArray = new Integer[] {1,2,3,4,5};
ArrayList<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
arrList.addAll(Arrays.asList(arrArray));
```

also initailising and declaring in one line :

```
Integer[] arrArray = new Integer[] {1,2,3,4,5};
ArrayList<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<Integer>(){{
addAll(Arrays.asList(arrArray));}};
```

or by element :

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<Integer>(){{
add(1);
add(2);
add(3);
}};
```

But now I would like to do the same thing, but now with multiple dimension arraylists (and Strings in this case):

```
private String[] arrFUSE={"3", "true", "0", "FUSE"};
private String[] arrPLACE={ "2", "true", "7", "PLACE"};
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrLIST = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(){{
add( Arrays.asList(arrFUSE) );
add( Arrays.asList(arrPLACE) );
}};
```

An other try

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrLIST = 
        new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(){{
            add(     
                  new ArrayList<String>(){{ addAll(Arrays.asList(arrFUSE))}};
            );
}};
```

Thanks on beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try casting `asList` result to `ArrayList`  since `asList` return of type `List`

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrLIST = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(){{
    add( (ArrayList<String>) Arrays.asList(arrFUSE) );
    add( (ArrayList<String>) Arrays.asList(arrPLACE) );
    }};
```

or change declaration to `List`

```
ArrayList<List<String>> arrLIST = new ArrayList<List<String>>(){{
    add( Arrays.asList(arrFUSE) );
    add( Arrays.asList(arrPLACE) );
    }};
```

Since you are implementing anonymous inners class right-away, there is no way to find out it's type which is present in outside of it's scope. That's where casting needed.

Comment: but usually is not neccessary to cast from `List` to `ArrayList`. `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>()` is ok... why casting in this case ???

Comment: @JordiCastilla Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] arrFUSE={"3", "true", "0", "FUSE"};                            
String[] arrPLACE={ "2", "true", "7", "PLACE"};                         
List<List<String>> arrLIST = new ArrayList<List<String>>();             
arrLIST.add( Arrays.asList(arrFUSE) );                                  
arrLIST.add( Arrays.asList(arrPLACE) );
```

Don't use `{` on the line you create a new instance of the `ArrayList`. If you do you will be writing your own implementation of `ArrayList` on the lines below it. In stead you just want to use the standard `ArrayList` so terminate that line and start a new one.

I also changed `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` to `List<List<String>>` because you want to be able to put any `List` in there, not just `ArrayLists`. In fact what `Arrays.asList` creates is not an `ArrayList` so it wouldn't fit otherwise.